# Python vampire number

Tags: python, python-3.x, numbers

First time posting in this community. I recently started to learn Python (2 weeks) and as a way to practice a classmate gave me a task: "Write a program that checks if an integer is a vampire number.
For an integer to be a vampire number(v) it needs to meet these 4 criteria:

1)Has a pair number of digits. Lets call the number of digits:n

2)You can obtain v by multiplying two integers,x and y, each with n/2 digits. x and y are the fangs.

3)Both fangs cannot end simultaneously in 0.

4)v can be made with all digits from x and y, in any order and only using each digit once.

Example:

21*60=1260 <--Vampire number

210*600=126000 <--Not a vampire number

The first vampire numbers are the following: 1260, 1395, 1435, 1530, 1827, 2187, 6880, 102510, 104260, 105210, 105264, 105750, 108135, 110758, 115672, 116725, 117067, 118440, 120600, 123354, 124483, 125248, 125433, 125460, 125500, 126027, 126846, 129640, ...

So far I've made a program that can achieve the first 3 criteria(I think). I'm looking for help on the last one.

This is what I've got: (Sorry for some stuff in Spanish)

```
v=int(input("Enter number to test for vampire:"))
#Test for pair number of digits
def nd(a):
    nd = 0
    while a != 0:
        d = a % 10
        if d != 0:
            nd += 1
        a = a // 10
    return nd
def DigitosPar(a):
    if nd(a)%2==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
#Last digit is 0
def UltimoDigCero(b):
    ud = 0
    ud = b % 10
    if ud==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

if DigitosPar(v)==1:
    x=[]
    for i in range(int(10**(nd(v)/2-1)),int(10**(int(nd(v))/2))):
        x.append(i)
    y=x
    z=0
    posiblex=0
    posibley=0
    for ia in range(0,len(y)):
        for ib in range(0,len(x)):
            z=y[ia]*x[ib]
            if z==v and not((UltimoDigCero(x[ib])==1 and UltimoDigCero(y[ia])==1)):
                posiblex=x[ib]
                posibley=y[ia]
                print(v,"has as fangs",posiblex,posibley)
    if posiblex==0:
        print(v, "not a vampire")
else:
    print(v, "not a vampire")
```

Comment: You don't have a question

Comment: Your code could use some cleanup, like the `UltimoDigCero` function: it assigns something to `ud`, then assigns something else, then checks whether an expression is `True` or `False` and explicitly returns one of those values. The whole function could just be `return not b%10` or `return b%10 == 0`.

Comment: @AndrewL.Just some help on the last criteria

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Thanks for the advice, will surely apply it and keep it in mind for future code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is fast method to get solutions for numbers that are 6 digits or longer:

```
import itertools as it

def get_fangs(num_str):
    num_iter = it.permutations(num_str, len(num_str))
    for num_list in num_iter:
        v = ''.join(num_list)
        x, y = v[:int(len(v)/2)], v[int(len(v)/2):]
        if x[-1] == '0' and y[-1] == '0':
            continue
        if int(x) * int(y) == int(num_str):
            return x,y
    return False

def is_vampire(m_int):
    n_str = str(m_int)
    if len(n_str) % 2 == 1:
        return False
    fangs = get_fangs(n_str)
    if not fangs:
        return False
    return True

for test_num in range(150000):
    if is_vampire(test_num):
        print ("{}".format(test_num), end = ", ")
```

And here is the output when I run this (in IDLE):

```
>>> 
================== RESTART: C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\vampire.py 
1260, 1395, 1435, 1530, 1827, 2187, 6880, 102510, 104260, 105210, 105264, 
105750, 108135, 110758, 115672, 116725, 117067, 118440, 120600, 123354, 
124483, 125248, 125433, 125460, 125500, 126027, 126846, 129640, 129775, 
131242, 132430, 133245, 134725, 135828, 135837, 136525, 136948, 139500, 
140350, 143500, 145314, 146137, 146952,  
==================
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

1260 is a vampire number because the divisors can be concatenated into a permutation of 1260. You can do it this way

```
v=int(input("Enter number to test for vampire:"))

from collections import Counter

def is_anagram(a, b):
    if len(a) != len(b):
        return False
    return Counter(a) == Counter(b)

import math
for x in range(0,int(math.pow(10, len(str(v))/2))):
        for y in range(0,int(math.pow(10, len(str(v))/2))):
            if (x*y == v):
                #print('Fangs: %d %d' % (x, y))
                if (is_anagram(str(str(x)+''+str(y)), str(v)) ):
                    print('Vampire')
```

To list the first `n`vampire numbers, you can use the above code as a function and incrementally test the integers.

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting way of looking at it. Could you please explain the function is_anagram you created? That's the part I can't understand.

Comment: @GonzaloXavier `is_anagram` checks that the 2 numbers are each other's permutations, treating the numbers as string. You can try and run `Counter(str(6120))` and look at the output. Different permutations of the same digits will return the same output e.g. `Counter(str(6120))==Counter(str(6210))` is `True`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :)

Comment: Code needs to be debugged. 126000 is returning as a 'Vampire', when it should not be, per the example given in the original post. You can refer to my answer to see how to fix it. The last character in both fangs should be checked for '0'.

Comment: @Joe I did realize that when I first ran it. However it helped me with the criteria I was missing. The 0 condition was already in my very messy code. Thanks for the input. Your code is great btw.